# Open Sans installed by default on all major OS's

Tags: fonts

Do all major operating systems have Open Sans installed by default? Ie, if my website uses Open Sans will it display on:

- Windows
- Mac OS
- Linux
- iOS
- Android

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: No, it is not installed on every operating system. If you website relies on a particular font, *ensure that font gets loaded* even if the OS is supposed to come with it, because you need a *specific version*. You want to rule out even the possibility of one flavour of linux using version 1.1 while another uses 3.4.1230 and looking wildly different. So use `@font-face` and load the exact version you need.

As a bonus, that will even override your *own* locally installed copy, so you are guaranteed to be looking at the same thing your users will be.